# Erroneous expression in a nonptr-new-declarator

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, new-operator, c++14

In [expr.new]/7 there is the following phrase:

> If the *expression*, after converting to `std::size_t`, is a core
>   constant expression and the expression is erroneous, the program is
>   ill-formed. Otherwise, a new-expression with an erroneous expression
>   does not call an allocation function and terminates by throwing an
>   exception of a type that would match a handler (15.3) of type
>   `std::bad_array_new_length`.

What is the relevance of distinguishing between an erroneous core constant expression and an expression that is just erroneous?

Comment: I would rather get a compiler error than an exception on `new int[-1]`, but the compiler can't make that check for `new int[f()]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The paragraph before the one you quoted expressed under which conditions the expression is *erroneous*. Essentially it boils down to the question whether the value is negative or too big. If so, it is an error.

A *core constant expression* is something the compiler can and will compute at compile time. If the corresponding expression can, thus, statically be determined to be erroneous, it is a compile-time error. If the the expression is not a constant, it may not be possible to determine its value during compile time. However, in that case an error would be detected at run-time and the error has to result in an exception.